# Looping through a list partition

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I got the following list and I would like to loop and partition this list in the following way.

```
list={{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,1},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{3,1},{3,2},{3,2,4},{3,2,5},{4,1},{4,2},{4,2,3},{4,2,5},{5,1},{5,2},{5,1,3},{5,1,4}}
```

List at loop 1=

```
{{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,1},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{3,1},{3,2},{3,2},{3,2},{4,1},
 {4,2},{4,2},{4,2},{5,1},{5,2},{5,1},{5,1}}
```

List at loop 2=

```
{{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{2,4},{2,5},{},{},{2,3},{2,5},{},{},{1,3},{1,4}}
```

`

Essentially, the results in the first stage should only include the first two elements of each {}. The Second stage then should include the second and third elements of the {} and so forth. In case we see a {} with n elements the loop should continue.

Any ideas how I could achieve this easily?

Best,

Julian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the idea?

```
list={{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,1},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{3,1},{3,2},{3,2,4},{3,2,5},{4,1},{4,2},{4,2,3},{4,2,5},{5,1},{5,2},{5,1,3},{5,1,4}}
MovingMap[Identity, #, 2] & /@ list // PadRight // ReplaceAll[#, {0, 0} -> {}] &
```

[image]

You could `Transpose` the result if needed.

*Edit*

`MovingMap` is new in version 10. A basic implementation is:

```
movingMap[f_, l_, w_] := f /@ Partition[l, w, 1]
```

after which you could just replace `MovingMap` above with `movingMap`.

It's not clear if you need the result to be rectangular. If not, I would do something like this:

```
#1 x + #2 y & @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ list
```

where `#1 x + #2 y &` is a function that does whatever you need to each window.

[image]

Comment: is MovingMap a comment in Mathematica 8? I cannot find it.

Comment: Oh, no, it is new in version 10. But you could implement it like this: `movingMap[f_, l_, w_] := f @@@ Partition[l, w, 1]`

Comment: How would this work exactly?

Comment: `MovingMap` works like this: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html. Replace `Identity` with a function that does whatever you want to do to each window. The `2` following it is the width of the windows. The `{0,0}` is an assumption that let me use the short form of `PadRight` -- if you would ever actually have `{0,0}` sequentially in your lists, then you should instead use the fuller form of `PadRight` (in docs) that lets you specify what the padding is (and then you could get rid of the `ReplaceAll`)

Comment: Sorry, I meant implementing the movingMap function. So how would you suggest using it in your above code sampel?

Comment: Oh gotcha. You'd just replace the system function. (See edit; note I used a slightly different definition for `movingMap` there).

Comment: You were a little bit lazy recently. Nice to see you here again and +1 for a +1 answer :)

Comment: Note that in V9 there is also the function `Developer\`PartitionMap` that will do what you require.

Answer (score 2):

I posted before reading other answers but now I feel a bit silly for not using [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) as mfvonh (implicitly) did.  I propose:

```
PadRight[Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ list, Automatic, {}]\[Transpose]
```

> ```
> {
>
>  {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 2},
>    {3, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 1}, {5, 1}},
>
>  {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {}, {}, {2, 3},
>    {2, 5}, {}, {}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}
>
> }
> ```

---

(old answer)

You could use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html), suppress error messages with [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quiet.html), then [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) `Part[ . . . ]` with `{}`:

```
pull[L_List, n_Integer] := Quiet[ #[[n ;; n + 1]] ] & /@ L /. _Part :> {}
```

Examples:

```
pull[list, 1]

pull[list, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 
>   2}, {3, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 1}, {5, 1}}
>
> {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {}, {}, {2, 3}, {2, 
>   5}, {}, {}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}
> ```

For all "pulls" perhaps:

```
Array[pull[list, #] &, Max[Length /@ list] - 1]
```